# Router in Closed Cabinet Okay

Tags: router, wireless-router, overheating

I know that it could overheat, but I have been having no symptoms of the router overheating. The router is a travel router and it has plenty of room inside and the cabinet has some vent holes where the door closes, little cracks.

Is it a high possibility that the router is overheating and having heat issues without me knowing? I have been opening up the compartment and putting my hand in and the air feels normal. Should I be concerned, would the air feel hot if it were to be overheating?

Answer (score 2):

Find the router's temperature specification by searching for the make/model online.  They can typically survive higher temps, but the specified highest temp is the one that the manufacturer will honor for warranty.

Leave a cheap thermometer in the cabinet, and check it at the hottest part of the day (1-3 PM).  If you're in the Southern Hemisphere, now in January is probably the hottest part of the year.  If you're in the Northern Hemisphere, then you want to check at the hottest part of day later months.  July/August will probably be hottest.

You can add some holes / vent lines at inconspicuous places on the cabinet.  The fact that some holes exist means that some airflow is already happening.  You have the option of putting a little fan in there if you're worried.  $1 from an electronics spare parts store.

If you want to be thorough, you can buy a little wifi thermometer.  It will cost a few dozen dollars, but then you'll have a little tool you can check on the internet that will continuously tell you what the temp is.  When you're satisfied that the cabinet is safe, you can use the thermometer in other projects.